# Type deduction for default constructor with defaulted template type

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++17, clang++

Assuming I have this example type:

```
template < class T = void > struct Test { };

template < > struct Test<void> { };
```

And this type deduction guide:

```
template<class T> Test() -> Test<T>;
```

The following compiles just fine:

```
Test f;
```

On GCC that is.

However, on Clang. The deduction guide needs to be:

```
template<class T = void> Test() -> Test<T>;
```

So my question is: **Which is the correct one?**

Should the default template type be present in both deduction and base type or just in base type and assume it'll be picked up by the compiler.

The trunk version of both GCC and Clang were tested with godbolt.org using `-O3 -std=c++17`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't actually need a deduction guide for this type - given that the class template parameter is already defaulted. If you do provide a deduction guide, it should be:

```
Test() -> Test<void>;
```

It doesn't make sense to make it a deduction guide template.

---

That said, I would argue that this isn't a bug... from either compiler. There's nothing *wrong* with writing a deduction guide that has non-deduced template parameters, as your example does:

> ```
> template<class T> Test() -> Test<T>;
> ```

But while that construct is allowed by the standard, it also makes no sense to ever actually do. The point of a deduction guide is to... guide deduction. If you provide a non-deducible deduction guide, what is the point of that? Clang erroring here seems quite helpful to me - it is alerting you to the fact that you wrote code that is clearly wrong.

If we're being pedantic, clang bug. But practically speaking, I prefer clang's result to gcc's.

Comment: Indeed, I was expecting something similar to Clang from from GCC as well. But more importantly, thank you for letting me know that I can go without having to involve templates.